# Can I add a dimmer switch for lighting to a GFI circuit in Kitchen?

Tags: electrical, kitchens

Goal:  I want to add some under cabinet lights in my kitchen and control them all from an in wall dimmer switch.

Problem: I have 3 outlets in my kitchen.  One is a GFI outlet, but the other two are on the same circuit.  I was assuming I could just add the dimmer switch by tapping off one of the normal outlets for power.  I have done this before (in a bedroom) and in that case, the outlet had an empty set of top lugs  that I could use to tap off of.  However, in the kitchen all the outlets (GFI and normal) have connections at all 4 lugs (white and black on bottom lugs - white and black on top lugs).

Question:  Can I/ How do I tap off of one of the normal outlets to add my dimmer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to stay complaint with code you cannot do this. You cannot tap off a kitchen receptacle circuit for lighting. Is it done, yeah, I'm sure it is. Is it correct or code complaint, no, not at all.
You need to find another circuit to take power from.

BTW, the fact that the screws are all used on the receptacles does not mean anything.

Comment: In other words: Use a pigtail to splice an extra connection to one of the non-GFI circuits.

Comment: @feetwet, no, in my words: "You cannot tap off a kitchen receptacle circuit for lighting."

Comment: Oh, I see the nuance now.  He doesn't say whether the other outlets are wired through the GFI.

Comment: The GFI has nothing to do with it. Lighting cannot be on a kitchen receptacle circuit

Comment: Can you provide a source for that in the NEC?  Getting into the details it appears that there have to be two dedicated appliance circuits in the kitchen, but there could be others that share receptacles and lighting.  Furthermore 210.52(B)(1) explicitly provides for an exception that appears to cover under-counter lighting.

Comment: There is no such exception for UC lighting. It talk about the "two or more small appliance branch circuits...". All counter and general use receptacle circuits in these rooms are small appliance branch circuits. 210.52(B)2 is VERY clear that SABC's "shall have no other outlets". This means any lighting and even a range hood.